# How to set input name attribute equal to a variable using Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I am new to Handlebars.js and I'm trying to figure out how to a name attribute on radio buttons based on a variable defined in my JS.

The below code currently gives the output I want except I would like to set the name attribute to different names according to the value of a variable. For example if the variable number were set to 4, I would like the name of all inputs to be 'answer4'.

A little extra background info: The number variable is set as an argument in the quiz function, i.e. quiz("quizJSONFile", number); I use the number to define which html elements to append quiz questions and answers to.

HTML:

```
<script id="radio-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}
        <input name='answer' type='radio' value='{{@index}}' >{{this}}<br>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

JS:

```
function createRadios(){
var radioScript = $("#radio-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(radioScript);
 $("#question").append(template(allQuestions[counter].choices));
};
```

JSON:

```
var allQuestions = [{
  question: "How many presidents were members of the Whig party?",
  choices: ["Four", "Three", "Two"],
  correct: 0
}, {
  question: "Who was the first president to be impeached?",
  choices: ["Andrew Jackson", "Andrew Johnson", "Warren Harding"],
  correct: 1
}, {
  question: "How many presidents died during their presidency?",
  choices: ["Four", "Six", "Eight"],
  correct: 2
}, {
  question: "How many presidents had no party affiliation?",
  choices: ["One", "Two", "Three"],
  correct: 0
}, {
  question: "Who was the only president to serve two non-consecutive terms, making him both the 22nd and 24th president?",
  choices: ["John Quincy Adams", "William Howard Taft", "Grover Cleveland"],
  correct: 2
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that to do this I needed to bring the variable inside the function that contains the Handlebars compiler, i.e. var quizNum = num;

HTML:

```
<script id="radio-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each this}}
            <input name={{answerSet}} type='radio' value={{@index}} >{{this}}<br>
        {{/each}}
</script>
```

JS:

```
function createRadios() {
        var quizNum = num;
        var radioScript = $("#radio-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(radioScript);
        Handlebars.registerHelper('answerSet', function () {
            return "quiz" + quizNum;
        });

        question.append(template(allQuestions[counter].choices));
    };
```